# How to display and play video links from TikTok, Instagram, Facebook and Youtube in flutter?

Tags: flutter, facebook, dart, instagram, tiktok

I want to display the videos that I share from other social medias into my flutter app through the urls which you get when you share videos, but I'm kinda stuck and don't know how to approach this. I played around with the [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html) package but I just can't figure how to display the videos and be able to play and pause it, Is this possible with flutter? if someone has any idea how to approach or solve this I would appreciate your help.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html_core/flutter_widget_from_html_core.dart';
import 'package:fwfh_webview/fwfh_webview.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var url1 =
        '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_QiF6JEp-oM?controls=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    var url2 =
        '<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=476&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F100052122941078%2Fvideos%2F1176244359569220%2F&show_text=false&width=476&t=0" width="476" height="476" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>';
    var url3 =
        '<blockquote class="tiktok-embed" cite="https://www.tiktok.com/@fbardha.hoxha/video/7037060870089772294" data-video-id="7037060870089772294" style="max-width: 605px;min-width: 325px;" > <section> <a target="_blank" title="@fbardha.hoxha" href="https://www.tiktok.com/@fbardha.hoxha">@fbardha.hoxha</a> <p> <a title="fy" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/fy">#fy</a> <a title="fypシ" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/fyp%E3%82%B7">#fypシ</a> <a title="foryou" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/foryou">#foryou</a> <a title="viral" target="_blank" href="https://www.tiktok.com/tag/viral">#viral</a></p> <a target="_blank" title="♬ original sound - Wily Williams" href="https://www.tiktok.com/music/original-sound-7006365955399994113">♬ original sound - Wily Williams</a> </section> </blockquote> <script async src="https://www.tiktok.com/embed.js"></script>';
    var url4 =
        '<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/tv/CWV3qAhKODK/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" data-instgrm-version="14" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:540px; min-width:326px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:16px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/tv/CWV3qAhKODK/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" style=" background:#FFFFFF; line-height:0; padding:0 0; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:100%;" target="_blank"> <div style=" display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center;"> <div style="background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 50%; flex-grow: 0; height: 40px; margin-right: 14px; width: 40px;"></div> <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: center;"> <div style=" background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 4px; flex-grow: 0; height: 14px; margin-bottom: 6px; width: 100px;"></div> <div style=" background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 4px; flex-grow: 0; height: 14px; width: 60px;"></div></div></div><div style="padding: 19% 0;"></div> <div style="display:block; height:50px; margin:0 auto 12px; width:50px;"><svg width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 60 60" version="1.1" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g transform="translate(-511.000000, -20.000000)" fill="#000000"><g><path d="M556.869,30.41 C554.814,30.41 553.148,32.076 553.148,34.131 C553.148,36.186 554.814,37.852 556.869,37.852 C558.924,37.852 560.59,36.186 560.59,34.131 C560.59,32.076 558.924,30.41 556.869,30.41 M541,60.657 C535.114,60.657 530.342,55.887 530.342,50 C530.342,44.114 535.114,39.342 541,39.342 C546.887,39.342 551.658,44.114 551.658,50 C551.658,55.887 546.887,60.657 541,60.657 M541,33.886 C532.1,33.886 524.886,41.1 524.886,50 C524.886,58.899 532.1,66.113 541,66.113 C549.9,66.113 557.115,58.899 557.115,50 C557.115,41.1 549.9,33.886 541,33.886 M565.378,62.101 C565.244,65.022 564.756,66.606 564.346,67.663 C563.803,69.06 563.154,70.057 562.106,71.106 C561.058,72.155 560.06,72.803 558.662,73.347 C557.607,73.757 556.021,74.244 553.102,74.378 C549.944,74.521 548.997,74.552 541,74.552 C533.003,74.552 532.056,74.521 528.898,74.378 C525.979,74.244 524.393,73.757 523.338,73.347 C521.94,72.803 520.942,72.155 519.894,71.106 C518.846,70.057 518.197,69.06 517.654,67.663 C517.244,66.606 516.755,65.022 516.623,62.101 C516.479,58.943 516.448,57.996 516.448,50 C516.448,42.003 516.479,41.056 516.623,37.899 C516.755,34.978 517.244,33.391 517.654,32.338 C518.197,30.938 518.846,29.942 519.894,28.894 C520.942,27.846 521.94,27.196 523.338,26.654 C524.393,26.244 525.979,25.756 528.898,25.623 C532.057,25.479 533.004,25.448 541,25.448 C548.997,25.448 549.943,25.479 553.102,25.623 C556.021,25.756 557.607,26.244 558.662,26.654 C560.06,27.196 561.058,27.846 562.106,28.894 C563.154,29.942 563.803,30.938 564.346,32.338 C564.756,33.391 565.244,34.978 565.378,37.899 C565.522,41.056 565.552,42.003 565.552,50 C565.552,57.996 565.522,58.943 565.378,62.101 M570.82,37.631 C570.674,34.438 570.167,32.258 569.425,30.349 C568.659,28.377 567.633,26.702 565.965,25.035 C564.297,23.368 562.623,22.342 560.652,21.575 C558.743,20.834 556.562,20.326 553.369,20.18 C550.169,20.033 549.148,20 541,20 C532.853,20 531.831,20.033 528.631,20.18 C525.438,20.326 523.257,20.834 521.349,21.575 C519.376,22.342 517.703,23.368 516.035,25.035 C514.368,26.702 513.342,28.377 512.574,30.349 C511.834,32.258 511.326,34.438 511.181,37.631 C511.035,40.831 511,41.851 511,50 C511,58.147 511.035,59.17 511.181,62.369 C511.326,65.562 511.834,67.743 512.574,69.651 C513.342,71.625 514.368,73.296 516.035,74.965 C517.703,76.634 519.376,77.658 521.349,78.425 C523.257,79.167 525.438,79.673 528.631,79.82 C531.831,79.965 532.853,80.001 541,80.001 C549.148,80.001 550.169,79.965 553.369,79.82 C556.562,79.673 558.743,79.167 560.652,78.425 C562.623,77.658 564.297,76.634 565.965,74.965 C567.633,73.296 568.659,71.625 569.425,69.651 C570.167,67.743 570.674,65.562 570.82,62.369 C570.966,59.17 571,58.147 571,50 C571,41.851 570.966,40.831 570.82,37.631"></path></g></g></g></svg></div><div style="padding-top: 8px;"> <div style=" color:#3897f0; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:550; line-height:18px;">View this post on Instagram</div></div><div style="padding: 12.5% 0;"></div> <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; margin-bottom: 14px; align-items: center;"><div> <div style="background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 50%; height: 12.5px; width: 12.5px; transform: translateX(0px) translateY(7px);"></div> <div style="background-color: #F4F4F4; height: 12.5px; transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(3px) translateY(1px); width: 12.5px; flex-grow: 0; margin-right: 14px; margin-left: 2px;"></div> <div style="background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 50%; height: 12.5px; width: 12.5px; transform: translateX(9px) translateY(-18px);"></div></div><div style="margin-left: 8px;"> <div style=" background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 50%; flex-grow: 0; height: 20px; width: 20px;"></div> <div style=" width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 2px solid transparent; border-left: 6px solid #f4f4f4; border-bottom: 2px solid transparent; transform: translateX(16px) translateY(-4px) rotate(30deg)"></div></div><div style="margin-left: auto;"> <div style=" width: 0px; border-top: 8px solid #F4F4F4; border-right: 8px solid transparent; transform: translateY(16px);"></div> <div style=" background-color: #F4F4F4; flex-grow: 0; height: 12px; width: 16px; transform: translateY(-4px);"></div> <div style=" width: 0; height: 0; border-top: 8px solid #F4F4F4; border-left: 8px solid transparent; transform: translateY(-4px) translateX(8px);"></div></div></div> <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; justify-content: center; margin-bottom: 24px;"> <div style=" background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 4px; flex-grow: 0; height: 14px; margin-bottom: 6px; width: 224px;"></div> <div style=" background-color: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 4px; flex-grow: 0; height: 14px; width: 144px;"></div></div></a><p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/tv/CWV3qAhKODK/?utm_source=ig_embed&amp;utm_campaign=loading" style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank">A post shared by Gjirafa50 Masters League (@gjirafa50mastersleague)</a></p></div></blockquote> <script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'fwfh_url_launcher',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('UrlLauncherFactory Demo'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: HtmlWidget(
                    url1,
                    factoryBuilder: () => MyWidgetFactory(),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: HtmlWidget(
                    url2,
                    factoryBuilder: () => MyWidgetFactory(),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: HtmlWidget(
                    url3,
                    factoryBuilder: () => MyWidgetFactory(),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: HtmlWidget(
                    url4,
                    factoryBuilder: () => MyWidgetFactory(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidgetFactory extends WidgetFactory with WebViewFactory {}
```

What I got: [image]

What I want: [image]

Comment: These plugins usually render inside an iframe, or create their own encapsulated shadow DOM - meaning, you can not interact with them with JS from your page. The provider of the specific widget would have to explicitly provide some sort of API via an embeddable script for you, to make stuff like play/pause via JS commands triggered by your app possible.

Comment: umm... I tried getting the embedded code for each video but some show and some don't for example the youtube video works perfectly but the other don't, why is that?

Comment: For example the Facebook iframe you have above, only gives me "Unavailable -
This video can't be embedded because it may contain content owned by someone else." - so this apparently got restricted for copyright reasons. You need to pick videos that actually _are_ embeddable, not all of them are.

Comment: Well you're right but still the Instagram and TikTok embedded video url don't work, could it be because the package that Im using says that it supports the ***Iframe*** tag but the embedded code that i get from Instagram and TikTok starts with ***blockquote*** if yes how should I deal with this? The link for the package: https://pub.dev/packages/fwfh_webview

Comment: You will have to find some package that allows you to insert raw HTML then, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Copy that "`blockquote`" code and render it somewhere and look to the generated DOM. You will see that it also contains an `script` tag, that loads the proper `iframe` inside the original `blockquote`.

I just had to add the TikTok embed but it won't work because it "needs" the `script` tag to create the `iframe`. But you can copy the `iframe` that it generates and use somewhere else.

They probably did like this so they can update the embed URL without breaking everyone that uses it.

By now, it generates an iframe with this URL: `https://www.tiktok.com/embed/v2/:videoId?lang=:lang`